# Where is the FAQ and who are the DB administrators?

Tags: support

Which questions can I ask here? DB administrators, are they coders or just people who simply install the SQL server and make sure that it has no viruses, is up and running? I actually wanted to ask a low-level question, basically, how persistence is ensured/assumed? When does the server does the flush? Can it happen that OS flush command propagates into some intermediate buffer and does not propagate down to the HDD plates? Today, many storage manufacturers and interfaces support out-of-order write buffers. What are implications? Should you take any action to counteract it? Does ram buffer on disk matter? Are any UPS (and which) required to support the RAM buffer? Are there any courses that teach safe storage?

What should I guarantee if I have my own "DB" - storing my data in plain files? I mean that DB does the best, what is the best so that I could guarantee that data is not lost.

These are pretty low-level questions and I am not sure if asking them from administrators is a proper idea. On the other hand, even if you is user rather than DB designer, you must know what are the OS and hard drive requirements.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer. You might want to leave it a while to see if that is the consensus view or not!

Comment: If I notice a better answer, I will pick it. Do not worry.

Comment: Good. I was just worried it might discourage other replies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant part of the FAQ is here.

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

It doesn't specifically indicate the "on topicness" of the subject area that you mention but questions about [database internals](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-internals) are often welcomed and receive good answers.

In my opinion a question asking about ACID compliance and issues surrounding write caching would be on topic for the site. But take care to make it reasonably scoped too avoid the "Too Broad" close reason.

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.